# How to setup Organization's Calendar in Sterling Commerce?

Tags: ibm-sterling

I have two warehouses under my organization. Those two warehouses have different holiday shifts. I tried to create separate calendar's through the participant modelling. But, I need to do something like inherited calendar. Please help me with this....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup calendar in the Configurator itself. In Participant modelling section you can create two warehouses as you did. After that create one calendar and specify the effective time periods and Holidays and Working days options.  Next you may create one more calendar and in that you can select the first calendar as the master. So the new calendar will be the child of the first one and specify the child's specific shift timings.

I hope this is the one which you are looking for. Good Luck.